# Java 12 intellij switch expressions doesn't work

Tags: java, intellij-idea, switch-statement, java-12, switch-expression

I try to use Java 12 in IntelliJ but when I try to run My app occurs error

```
Error:(57, 32) java: switch expressions are a preview feature and are disabled by default.
  (use --enable-preview to enable switch expressions)
```

I added in app configuration VM option --enable-preview but this error  still occurs. I added SDK paths. Anyone have idea what I do wrong?

```
List<Car> sortedCars = switch (sortType) {
    case COLOR -> cars.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Car::getColor)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    case MILEAGE -> cars.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Car::getMileage)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    case MODEL -> cars.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Car::getModel)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    case PRICE -> cars.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Car::getPrice)).collect(Collectors.toList());
};
```

Comment: which intellij version?

Comment: @SebastianS IDEA 2019.1.1

Comment: As a side note, try to avoid code duplication, as otherwise, you are ignoring the actual benefit of switch expressions. Consider `List<Car> sortedCars = cars.stream().sorted(  switch (sortType) { case COLOR ->   Comparator.comparing(Car::getColor); case MILEAGE -> Comparator.comparing(Car::getMileage); case MODEL ->   Comparator.comparing(Car::getModel); case PRICE ->   Comparator.comparing(Car::getPrice); }  ).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Avoid duplication even further: `List<Car> sortedCars = cars.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(switch (sortType) { case COLOR -> Car::getColor; case MILEAGE -> Car::getMileage; case MODEL -> Car::getModel; case PRICE -> Car::getPrice; } ).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 6):

By default the Language Level is set to "*12 - No new language feature*". You need to change it to "*12 (Preview) - Switch Expression*" and you will get a popup to accept the Preview changes. Post which you will be able to run switch expressions in intellij.

**Language Levels Settings**

[image: JDK 12 Preview]

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.1 (Community Edition)

Comment: When you run from Intellij do you see `--enable-preview` appended in the terminal? Can you share your execution logs or screenshot ?

Comment: did you figure it out?

Answer (score 4):

Please make sure that the "Project language level" setting in the Project Structure dialog for your project is set to Java 12. In this case, IntelliJ IDEA will add the --enable-preview option automatically.

The VM options field in the run configuration affects how your application is launched, not how it's compiled, so adding that option there has no effect.