# switch expressions are not supported at language level 12

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Latest `IntelliJ 2021.2.1 Community Edition` doesn't let me compile sources of Java 12, that include *switch expression*s, with "Language Level 12", giving either:

> switch expressions are not supported at language level '12'
> or
> Enhanced 'switch' blocks are not supported at language level '12'

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55888406/java-12-intellij-switch-expressions-doesnt-work), mandating to set the language level to `Java 12 Preview - Switch Expression`, but it's not available in the latest `IntelliJ`.

[image]

Seriously? what am I supposed to do? set the language-level to `14`? but I particularly want `12`, and preview features must be available for `12`.

What shall I do?

Comment: Please see the discussion at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-266128. Once a final JDK with these features is released, we no longer support a preview of it in the previous JDK versions.

Comment: @CrazyCoder super, super, super bad decision! just horrible one. And what if I want to demonstrate or reproduce something, with particularly Java 12 language?

Comment: Use an older IntelliJ IDEA version from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/previous.html.

Comment: ..and for which older version should I go to enable 12 preview features?.. what if I'm in Java 15, 16 or another preview features? how shall I then select which older versions of IntelliJ to download? shall I spent hours for matching the IntelliJ and Java versions? absolutely unpractical and bad decision.

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/supported-java-versions.html. Switch expressions preview with Java 12 support is available in IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.

Comment: Come one, please.. "Preview Features" are released very often! and if I, say, happen to be on the JDK 17, or even more - JDK 21, I should be keeping the track of which older versions of IntelliJ supported which particular Preview Features, which - not.. I should also ask to my students to bear 5 different versions of IDE and install all those on my machine as well.. just WHY? WHY on earth you've decided to go with this policy? was it taking too much to just keep the Language Syntax supported? to just keep one more option in the drop-down list? a truly, absolutely wrong and bad decision.

Comment: We understand that it's not convenient, but at the moment there are no plans to support it. Sorry.